# How to prevent a custom post type from using the archive.php template?

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I have the following:

```
//Jobs
register_post_type( 'jobs',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Jobs' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Job' )
        ),
    'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'revisions','author', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'page-attribute' ),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'jobs', 'with_front' => true),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', 'category'),
        'can_export' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    //'capability_type'=>'jobs',
    //'capabilities' => array(
    //  'read_post' => 'read_jobs'
    //),
    )
);
```

I tried this: `'has_archive' => false,`

But the Jobs custom post type is still using the `archive.php` template.

Any ideas of what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to use a specialized archive template for your custom type, you need an additional archive file. This is named in the form of:

`archive-[custom post type name].php`

Since your code listing has `jobs` as the type name, the archive file would be named:

`archive-jobs.php`

This can resemble the standard archive template, or can be tailored as suits the nature of the custom content type.